# Symfony turning listener with lifecycleevent into subscriber

Tags: php, symfony, events, doctrine, subscriber

I try some basic stuff in Symfony 3.1.5 on my own UserBundle.

First of all, I had a listener that worked. When I create a User, I use it to hash my password and change some stuff.

I declare it in the service.yml:

```
 #listener user pass et role
 user.listener.user:
    class: Willuna\UserBundle\Listener\UserSigninListener
    arguments: [ '@doctrine', '@security.password_encoder' ]
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener }
```

And the listener look like this:

```
<?php
namespace Willuna\UserBundle\Listener;

use Willuna\UserBundle\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoder;
/**
 * Description of UserSigninListener
 *
 */
class UserSigninListener {

private $doctrine;
private $password;

public function __construct(Registry $doctrine, UserPasswordEncoder $password) {
    $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
    $this->password = $password;
}

public function prePersist(User $user, LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
    // I hash and do some stuff in user
    $user->setPassword($this->password->encodePassword($user, $user->getPassword()));

}
}
```

Now, I want to send a confirmation Email after creating a user. 
I tryed doing another listener but iy didn't worked.

So I forget my listener, and turned it into a subscriber. It gaves me errors about the arguments and typeint in my method.

Here my User entity:

```
<?php
namespace Willuna\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Willuna\UserBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="email", message="Email already taken")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="username", message="Username already taken")
 * @ORM\EntityListeners({"Willuna\UserBundle\Subscriber\SigninSubscriber"})
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    ...
```

my Service.yml :

```
    user.subscriber.signin:
        class: Willuna\UserBundle\Subscriber\SigninSubscriber
        arguments: [ '@security.password_encoder' , '@doctrine' ]
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber}
```

The beautiful subscriber :

```
<?php
namespace Willuna\UserBundle\Subscriber;

use Willuna\UserBundle\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoder;
use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber; 
//use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
//use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

/**
 * class SigninSubscriber
 *
 */
class SigninSubscriber implements EventSubscriber {
    private $password;
    private $doctrine;

    public function __construct(UserPasswordEncoder $password, Registry $doctrine) {
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->doctrine= $doctrine;
    }


    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            'prePersist',
            'postPersist'
        );
    }

    public function prePersist(User $user, LifecycleEventArgs $args ){
        //change password and change my user

    }

    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args){
        //then I want to send an email 
    }
}
```

I've change my code to look like [the documentation of subscribers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html#creating-the-subscriber-class)

Finally, I still have this error when I create my new user :

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to Willuna\UserBundle\Subscriber\SigninSubscriber::__construct() 
must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoder, 
none given, called in /var/www/cours/SYMFONY/willuna-dolls/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/DefaultEntityListenerResolver.php on line 73
```

If I change the order of args, it will say the same error about Registry.

If I erase all args, it will say the same error about the args in my method `prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)`.

So here are the questions:

Is it possible to create a subscriber with lifecycle event and @doctrine and @encoder in args ?

Am I blind?

Did I miss something?

PS : First time I ask for help in a forum \o/.... except for my hemoroid problems. Just kidding XD.

Sorry for the long post. 
[Here is a potatoe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7txA.jpg)

Comment: I tried it my self, and got no problem with it... did you tried to remove the `@doctrine` from your dependencies (never inject doctrine or entity manager in a doctrine listener) ?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for trying to rescue me : )
I've tryed to delete `@doctrine` and then `@security.password_encoder`, and then the problem goes with my prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args ). It says my $args is an instance of User.

`Type error: Argument 1 passed to Willuna\UserBundle\Subscriber\SigninSubscriber::prePersist() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs, instance of Willuna\UserBundle\Entity\User given `

Comment: looking to your prePersist method, you are asking for it : `public function prePersist(User $user, LifecycleEventArgs $args)`. This method signature MUST be `public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)`